# android pinch zoom

Tags: android, pinchzoom, zooming

My layout contains buttons, textviews, etc. Is it possible to implement pinch zoom in my layout?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Code can be found here : [official-doc](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale#kotlin)

**Answer Outdated**

Check out the following links which may help you

Best examples are provided in the below links, which you can refactor to meet your requirements.

1. [Implementing the pinch zoom gesture](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847)
2. [Android-pinch](http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch/)
3. [GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html)

Comment: This answer will be worthless, once the links go down. At least quote the relevant parts.

Comment: FYI, this answer is out-of-date. [ScaleGestureDetector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html) is Android's answer for pinch-zoom, since API 8. See [Emanuel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11722858/199364).

Answer (score 38):

For android 2.2+ (api level8), you can use ScaleGestureDetector.

you need a member:

```
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
```

in your constructor (or onCreate()) you add:

```
mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new OnScaleGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        Log.d(LOG_KEY, "zoom ongoing, scale: " + detector.getScaleFactor());
        return false;
    }
});
```

You override onTouchEvent:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}
```

If you draw your View by hand, in the onScale() you probably do store the scale factor in a member, then call invalidate() and use the scale factor when drawing in your onDraw().
Otherwise you can directly modify font sizes or things like that in the onScale().

Comment: Additional information in [Android docs - Dragging and Scaling](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html)  Especially note example code showing how to combine panning (scrolling) with scaling (pinch zoom).

Answer (score 16):

I implemented a pinch zoom for my `TextView`, using [this](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847) tutorial. The resulting code is this:

```
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
```

and in onCreate():

```
    // Zoom handlers
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

        // We can be in one of these 2 states
        static final int NONE = 0;
        static final int ZOOM = 1;
        int mode = NONE;

        static final int MIN_FONT_SIZE = 10;
        static final int MAX_FONT_SIZE = 50;

        float oldDist = 1f;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    oldDist = spacing(event);
                    Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                    if (oldDist > 10f) {
                       mode = ZOOM;
                       Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM" );
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == ZOOM) {
                        float newDist = spacing(event);
                        // If you want to tweak font scaling, this is the place to go.
                        if (newDist > 10f) {
                            float scale = newDist / oldDist;

                            if (scale > 1) {
                                scale = 1.1f;
                            } else if (scale < 1) {
                                scale = 0.95f;
                            }

                            float currentSize = textView.getTextSize() * scale;
                            if ((currentSize < MAX_FONT_SIZE && currentSize > MIN_FONT_SIZE)
                                    ||(currentSize >= MAX_FONT_SIZE && scale < 1)
                                    || (currentSize <= MIN_FONT_SIZE && scale > 1)) {
                                textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, currentSize);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            return false;
        }
```

Magic constants 1.1 and 0.95 were chosen empirically (using `scale` variable for this purpose made my `TextView` behave kind of weird).

Comment: Can i know your `MyGestureDetector()` class

Comment: @Renanlf That was more than a year ago. Sorry, I don't even code for android anymore. Nor do I have those sources anywhere.

Comment: `MyGestureDetector()` is not relevant here; because of the declaration `GestureDetector(GestureDetector.OnGestureListener listener)` we conclude that it's a misnomer child of `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener`. And the events detected by that class are irrelevant for pinch zooming.

Comment: switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK), in this line of the code:
ACTION_MASK turns 255 (ff) so what is the point of adding Motion.ACTION_MASK? Will switch (event.getAction()) be enough, if not why? Could you please explain it.

Comment: @folone
Could you help me in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187772/how-to-pass-pinch-zoom-event-from-a-viewgroup-to-multiple-child-views) question. This question is similar to what I am facing

Comment: The code does not seeem to work. `MyGestureDetector` is not defined, and so are other things in the code, like `spacing`, `TAG`, ...)

Answer (score 5):

There is also this project that does the job and worked perfectly for me:
https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Answer (score 4):

In android Honeycomb(API Level 11), it is possible, We can use `setScaleX` and `setScaleY` with pivot point
I have explained it here

1. [Zooming a view completely](http://myandroidnote.blogspot.com/2011/03/zooming-view-completely.html)
2. [Pinch Zoom to view completely](http://myandroidnote.blogspot.com/2011/03/pinch-zoom-to-view-completely.html)

Comment: link only answers get worthless the the links get broken. Try adding a few main key points to the answer independent of the links

Answer (score 1):

I have created a project for basic pinch-zoom that supports Android 2.1+

Available [here](https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview)

Answer (score 0):

I have an open source library that does this very well. It's a four gesture library that comes with an out-of-the-box pan zoom setting. You can find it here: https://bitbucket.org/warwick/hacergestov3
Or you can download the demo app here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.WarwickWestonWright.HacerGestoV3Demo
This is a pure canvas library so it can be used in pretty any scenario.
Hope this helps.