# Android: Custom view Zoom/Pinch

Tags: android, graph, zooming, android-custom-view

I've a running graph library developed with onDraw plotting the graph using canvas.drawLine methods. In onTouch I've implemented scroll functionality.

Now my customer wants Zoom/Pinch. Is it possible to perform zoom/pinch on such a view without redrawing for these operations?

What is the best way to implement this?

Now next..
How can I display Zooming indicators for this?? 
I've some how managed to display scale of zoom (scaleFactor * 100). How will I show a zooming indicator? I can display static images using canvas.drawBitmap. But is there a more better way?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hey! Ramya, have you implemente scroll and zoom on your graph?

Comment: Yes. Long time back. I had mostly got the logic from Vinayak's comment/reference link

Comment: ok thanks, i will chack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a pinch zoom capability to the graph:

How to implement pinch zoom refer : [android pinch zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375817/android-pinch-zoom/5376108#5376108)