# Android: Custom view Zoom/Pinch to display zooming indicators

Tags: android, zooming, pinch, android-custom-view

I've implemented Zoom/Pinch using the approach said in [android pinch zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375817/android-pinch-zoom/5376108#5376108)
How can I display Zooming indicators for this?? I've some how managed to display scale of zoom (scaleFactor * 100). How will I show a zooming indicator? I can display static images using canvas.drawBitmap. But is there a more better way?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used the built-in ZoomButtonsController