# Android Drag, Pinch Scale, and Rotate Objects

Tags: java, android

Does anyone have a resource or suggestion on how to learn how to do pinch scale, drag/pan, and rotation of objects on Android.  I have completed an app for iOS and all of these features were seamless integrated, but I'm not sure where to start with Android.

The purpose of the app is to simply drag images from a menu onto a "canvas" and rotate/scale those images.

Do I use a surface view and simply drag on ImageViews? Does Android have pre built gestures (like pinch)?  How do I work with the point coordinate system to have objects move where the finger is touching?

Could someone point me in the right direction so I can learn how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android pinch zoom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375817/android-pinch-zoom)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the perfect tutorial for you:

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847?tag=content;siu-container