# android ImageView in ViewPager - implementing touch gesture zoom of image

Tags: java, android, touch

I have a ViewPager and ImageView based class as its children. In ImageView i can intercept touch events and use ScaleGestureDetector. Question is how to implement image zooming with gestures so that it works like any modern Android image viewer?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [pinch & zoom tutorial](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847)

This was already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5376296/313745