# How to zoom normal views in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

In my application, I would like to add zoom functionality to my views. Like in an activity I am displaying `LinearLayout` etc. But as of now what I know a view can be zoomed in only in `WebView` and not in normal view. After all what I want is to zoom in/zoom out feature similar to `WebView` in my normal views.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a Custom Layout extending Liner Layout or any other. Override its onDraw function and  and provide zooming functionality manually. There are many example at SO for zooming. You can follow them..
This might help:

[android pinch zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375817/android-pinch-zoom/5376108#5376108)

[How to apply pinch zoom on Gallery in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390367/how-to-apply-pinch-zoom-on-gallery-in-android)