# Android Pinch-to-zoom text

Tags: android

i want to do pinch to zoom text in android how can do this .I`ve seen many example but they are related to pinch to zoom image any help will be honorable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375817/android-pinch-zoom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to display your text would be the easiest way to achieve pinch-zoom. You can use the `WebView`'s `loadData` method to display your text.