# How to get RawX and RawY of both multi-touch points

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am making an app that needs pinch zoom and drag pan for a relative view.  When I first implemented drag pan it jumped all over the place.  Using `getRawX` and `getRawY` fixed my problems.  I am now working on pinch zoom and my app is once again jumping all over the place.  I tried using `getRawX`, but apparently I can only do that for one of the points.  It does not allow something like `event.getRawX(0);` and `event.getRawX()` will only return the values for one of the points.  How can I get RawX for both touchpoints?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out.  Nice job me

```
    float x = (event.getXPrecision()*event.getX(0)) - (event.getXPrecision()*event.getX(1));
    float y = (event.getYPrecision()*event.getY(0)) - (event.getYPrecision()*event.getY(1));
```

So basically event.getXPrecision()*event.getX(0) is the getRawX of pointer(0)

Comment: This doesn't get you the raw x/y values. Multiplying by the precision values just gives you the actual hardware coordinates. You'll still get relative values per the documentation. The reason this solves your problem is probably because what you really wanted was the distance between the two fingers, in which it won't matter if you use relative or absolute coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to record both fingers separately as the screen is touched. Then track the drag gesture as the fingers are moved.

[I found this resource super helpful](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847).

[A link to a similar post that solves the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375817/android-pinch-zoom)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `getX (int pointerIndex)` and `getY (int pointerIndex)`. Those 2 functions are defined here [Developer android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getX%28%29), for more detail how to get `pointerIndex`: [Pointer Index](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html)

Comment: getX and getY do not work.  They cause the "jumping" I'm experiencing.