# How to add pinch-zoom functionality to an android page?

Tags: android, pinchzoom

I have created an application that has one class with multi spinners, edit texts and buttons. I am wondering can pinch-zoom be added to this page and what is the best way to go about it? I have looked around for the past couple of hours but there seems to be many ways of doing it and most are on images! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: r u using web-view for displaying page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android pinch zoom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375817/android-pinch-zoom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from [stackOverflow:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5376108/2219600)

Check out the following links which may help you

Best examples are provided in the below links, which you can refactor to meet your requirements.

1. [implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gestur](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847)
2. [Android-pinch](http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch/)
3. [GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html)