# How to make an comic app with image files in the assets folder?

Tags: android

I want to make an app to view my own comic but i don't now how can i do that.
I just want a simple image viewer to view my images and a few features like:

zoom (with double tap and pinch),
  slide to open next or previous image(like gallery app),

please help me to do that.

I am very eager to your help. 
I know what source codes are if you send them to me.

please tell me anything that you thing can be helpful for me.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way do this is by using Pagecurl View because this animation fits to comics or magazine app. refer to this link below.

https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl

And for zooming try to refer this link.

[android pinch zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375817/android-pinch-zoom)

-note: if your asking someone to do that for you, well this is not the right place to ask.