# How to implement pinch-zoom feature for camera preview

Tags: android, camera, zooming, surfaceview, pinch

i tried pinch-zoom feature for image from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375817/android-pinch-zoom).it works fine but how can i implement pinch-zoom feature for camera preview.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is what I used to add pinch to zoom. The link to the code is here:
https://github.com/maxtower/AndroidDocumentScanner/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/martin/opencv4android/CameraPreview.java

```
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
float mDist = 0;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Get the pointer ID
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    int action = event.getAction();


    if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
        // handle multi-touch events
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
            mDist = getFingerSpacing(event);
        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && params.isZoomSupported()) {
            mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
            handleZoom(event, params);
        }
    } else {
        // handle single touch events
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            handleFocus(event, params);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private void handleZoom(MotionEvent event, Camera.Parameters params) {
    int maxZoom = params.getMaxZoom();
    int zoom = params.getZoom();
    float newDist = getFingerSpacing(event);
    if (newDist > mDist) {
        //zoom in
        if (zoom < maxZoom)
            zoom++;
    } else if (newDist < mDist) {
        //zoom out
        if (zoom > 0)
            zoom--;
    }
    mDist = newDist;
    params.setZoom(zoom);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
}

public void handleFocus(MotionEvent event, Camera.Parameters params) {
    int pointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
    int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(pointerId);
    // Get the pointer's current position
    float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
    float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

    List<String> supportedFocusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
    if (supportedFocusModes != null && supportedFocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
        mCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean b, Camera camera) {
                // currently set to auto-focus on single touch
            }
        });
    }
}

/** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
private float getFingerSpacing(MotionEvent event) {
    // ...
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return (float)Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}
```

Comment: it works but it must be added a line for this member data: private float mDist;

Comment: link is dead for github content !

Comment: working perfectly.. nice work.. thnxx !

Comment: thanks :) works for me

Comment: Above link is broken

Comment: I copy/pasted the relevant parts

Comment: lost clarity after adding this

Comment: add complete code

Comment: @UmaAchanta the complete code is available at the github link.

Comment: After adding this in my code I lost click event on Button as well as edittext

Comment: works well.  only change I ended up making was making the zoom on pinch a little more sensitive