# Adding Swipe gesture zoom to my Android Camera App

Tags: android, api, android-camera, gesture, android-camera2

I am new to Camera API and building a simple camera app where I have built the basic camera working layout but I am missing clue to incorporate the zoom features I want the app and its codebase as simple as possible , `I want to implement swipe up to zoom in and swipe down to zoom out feature`.
I have already implemented the basic camera which captures image - what should be added to achieve that desired functionality(swipe to zoom gesture) only ?Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the MotionEvent class to handle this. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594602/how-to-implement-pinch-zoom-feature-for-camera-preview

Comment: But that answer refers to pinch zoom , I want to implement swipeup to zoom

Answer (score 0):

You detect the swipeUp Event using SimpleOnGestureListener and use the zoom functionality accordingly.You can refer this  [How to detect swipe direction between left/right and up/down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095494/how-to-detect-swipe-direction-between-left-right-and-up-down)