# Zoomable Imageview or Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity that has just a image to show like graphical help. It has a lots of info and needs to be zoomed. I searched alot in diffrent sites and they say imageview is not zoomable. and i found complicated algoritjhms for it. i want to make my programm to zoom like many usual proggrams that zoom like my 2 fingers get further image zooms in and if they get close zooms out and and i want to user be able to move postion if image in image view bye moving his finger on it.if its impossible can i make that as background and do these functions on whole activity? thanks for helping

Comment: " I searched alot in diffrent sites and they say imageview is not zoomable. and i found complicated algoritjhms for it." Yes, that's how all those "many usual proggrams" do. Applying complicate algorithms. If you don't want to create it yourself, I'm sure there're several open source options you can grab the code on github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375817/android-pinch-zoom) should have everything you need to implement the pinch zoom. Alternatively you could have a look at the [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library; an implementation of [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) that supports zooming.