# scaling around mid point of two fingers in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-canvas, horizontalscrollview

I have a `HorizontalScrollView` in which there are multiple views inside it. I have implemented `pinch zoom gesture` in which multiple views, which are between my two fingers, are scaled.

But I am facing one glitch. When I am doing pinch zoom, the mid point of pinch zoom is moving but for user experience I want this point to be remain fixed and other things should adjust itself  while scaling so that mid point remains static.

Can someone tell me how to do it.

`onDraw()` method of custom view is

```
                Rect r =new Rect(0, 0, 700, 40);

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        float kk=mScaleFactor;    //this variable will be set by pinch zoom event and represent how much to scale
        sf*=kk;                   // this view must scale according to previous scaling  


        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(sf , 1);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE); 
        canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
        width=sf*700;
        canvas.restore();
        requestLayout();                               //this will change view width to fit the expanded rectangle 
        }
```

onMeasure method is called on requestLayout

```
        @Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,
              int heightMeasureSpec) {
            setMeasuredDimension((int)width, 340);
          }
```

The above custom view is called 12 times by a subclass of `HorizontalScrollView`. So there are 12 child views of `HorizontalScrollview`.

In this class I am doing the following things

1. Detecting the touch coordinates of two fingers.
2. Calculating the index of child view on which first finger is touched.
3. Calculating the index of child view on which second finger is touched.
4. Passing scale factor of pinch zoom to all the child views between start and last.
   These two indices are calculated in previous two step.
5. And finally invalidate() is called on the child view. So child can scale itself according to scale factor passed by parent view.

But there is one problem here. The mid point of two finger should remain static and other things should adjust during scaling. But my mid point is moving with scaling.

Can someone help me in doing this. Please tell me if any part of code is require.

Code of gesture listener of `HorizontalScrollview` is

```
      private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
               mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

            ViewGroup pp=takeparent(); //give object of this class

            for(int i=start;i<=last;i++)
            {
                LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)pp.getChildAt(i);
                DrawView view=(DrawView)ll.findViewById(R.id.drawview);
                view.mScaleFactor=mScaleFactor;
                view.invalidate();
                view.donesf=true;
            }
```

Sample app of mine
[image]

Edits as suggested in comments:

```
        private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
               mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

            ViewGroup pp=takeparent(); pp contains all the custom child views

            //start and last are indices of range of child for which we have to apply gesture
            for(int i=start;i<=last;i++)
            {
                LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)pp.getChildAt(i);
                DrawView view=(DrawView)ll.findViewById(R.id.drawview);

                view.mScaleFactor=mScaleFactor;
                view.pivotx=detector.getFocusX()+view.getLeft();
                view.pivoty=detector.getFocusY()+view.getTop();
                view.invalidate();
            }




            return true;
        }
```

This is custom view onDraw method

```
       public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        sf=mScaleFactor  //this scale factor is set by parent view    
        width=sf*700;  //this width will be use to rescale the view's width in requestLayout()

        canvas.save();

        canvas.scale(sf,1,pivotx,pivoty);  //pivotX and pivotY are also set by parent's onScale method of gestureListener
        canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
        requestLayout();
        canvas.restore();

        }
```

[image]

Comment: static mid point? i dont understand that

Comment: @pskink
With static mid point I mean, for the whole gesture that point should not change. You can ignore static word.

Comment: sorry, it does not tell me much...

Comment: I have added a image of my app. So when I pinch zoom with my fingers at Feb and April and lets say mid point of my finger lies at second line of March. I want the position of this line to be fixed. But now, as all the views are scaling around (0,0). The mid point of my finger is going to right side.
So the expected behavior when I pinch zoom for previous case is Feb view should expand on left side and April view should expand on right side. So March view's mid point should remain static.
But currently all views are expanding to right. So mid point is going to right. Hope I am clear this time.

Comment: so you need Canvas.scale with 4 params, not 2

Comment: @pskink Yes I know I have to scale child views with respect to some pivots rather than scaling with respect to (0,0). Can you tell me how to pass pivots to child views. Because these pivots are relative to views.

Comment: if the pivot is x,y in the parent, then you have to translate it by getLeft(), getTop() in the child

Comment: @pskink
I have done as told by you but then to the middle point is not static. Please suggest me, if I could have done anything extra. I have added my code in question.

Comment: tried detector.getFocusX()-view.getLeft() ? the same for pivot y

Comment: @pskink
Very sorry but it is still not working. Please suggest some other way.
Thank You very much again for your time

Comment: @pskink I think I have found a better approach. I will scroll by the same amount as my mid point is shifting. So midpoint will remain where it was

Answer (score 0):

For a view you are scaling, you can set the "invariant" point that should not move using `setPivotX()` and `setPivotY()`.  When I use a `ScaleGestureDetector`, I use the `focus` point for this.  For example:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
    {
        ...
        mScaledView.setPivotX(detector.getFocusX());
        mScaledView.setPivotY(detector.getFocusY());
        ...
```

I'm not sure if you want to do this with all of the children, or just the parent view, in your case, but usually you just need to do this to a single "parent" view and it will work properly for the children of that view.

Related to this, I didn't quite understand why you're passing the scaling factor down to each child when scaling the parent view will scale all of its children too.  Maybe you just need to add a single `FrameLayout` (or some other `ViewGroup` descendent) into your `HorizontalScrollView` that hosts the children and then just scale that (after setting its pivot appropriately)?

---

**Updated re comment**

Given that you only want to scale the views in the pinched region between the fingers, I believe you have a couple options, depending on your app:

1) Dynamically add just those views to an intermediate `FrameLayout` which gets scaled and has its pivot set, leaving the non-scaled views as direct children of the `HorizontalScrollView`; or

2) Passing down the focus point to each scaled child view after first adjusting for the child's position.  For example, assuming your `DrawView` either directly or indirectly inherits from `android.view.View`, which I would strongly recommend, then you can do something like:

```
    for (int i = start; i <= last; i++) {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)pp.getChildAt(i);
        DrawView view = (DrawView)ll.findViewById(R.id.drawview);

        view.setScaleX(mScaleFactor);
        view.setScaleY(mScaleFactor);
        view.setPivotX(detector.getFocusX() - view.getLeft());    // Note: minus, not plus...
        view.setPivotY(detector.getFocusY() - view.getTop());
        view.invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: I am passing scale factor only to some children which are between my fingers when pinch zoom is started. So if I am not wrong, if we scale parent view it will scale all of its children.
Now can you suggest me some way to pass this pivot to target children so that they can scale around it.

Comment: @user3265443 ah ha, now I think I understand what you want.  I just updated my answer.  Good luck.

Comment: But thanks for your answer but there is one problem here. Here the width of the view is not changing. So rectangle is hiding from its ends.

Comment: @user3265443 I'm not sure what you want here. Do you want the width of the view to change? Looking at your picture, I'm guessing you would rather have the subviews stay in their "month box", right? But if you want the width of the view to change such that you can scroll over it, you will probably want to do something more like my option 1 in the answer and change the layout width and height of your intermediate `FrameLayout` based on the scaling. (Also, I'm assuming you already realized that the code you added to your question should use minus instead of plus when correcting for top/left.)

Comment: I have added a image. So when I pinch zoom September view(refer second image), the width of the view should change to adjust scaled rectangle. Previously I am multiplying width with Scale factor and then calling requestLayout() method in child view's onDraw method. But this method is not working with your code. See my code of onDraw method

Comment: I have also added the code of requestLayout method of view. Please see the code

Comment: If we assume that the view is ImageView, replace
`imageView.setScaleX(mScaleFactor);
imageView.setScaleY(mScaleFactor);
imageView.setPivotX(detector.getFocusX() - imageView.getLeft());
imageView.setPivotY(detector.getFocusY() - imageView.getTop());
imageView.invalidate();`

with
`Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX() - imageView.getLeft(), detector.getFocusY() - imageView.getTop());
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);`

then, why is there a glitch? Both these code should behave identically, right?