# How to implement both pinch zoom and pan in android?

Tags: java, android, mobile, zooming

I need to implement a pinch zoom and pan to execute for same imageView.
How can i to do this?

Comment: most likely the better idea is to draw a Bitmap by yourself since you have the full control of drawing

Comment: You can see below http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_gestures.htm Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375817/android-pinch-zoom

Comment: the answer is below, i don't need more down-votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You below lib :-

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

**XML**

```
  <uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView
            android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

**JAVA**

```
    ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);
```

hope above lib will helps you.