# drawable xml background zoom in zoom out android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, zooming, squid

Hi I'm using drawable XML background, i want to zoom-in zoom out image by two fingers. When i zoom in background XML cover all background with same background XML(not blur background). You can check Squid App, same as that.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you add screenshots explaining this ?

Comment: Sure Sir Please wait

Comment: [PinchZoom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375817/android-pinch-zoom) try to use it

Comment: @PawandeepKaur the above added image is the zoomed one or default? Please add both images of zoomed and default so that one can understand your requirement.

Comment: @Shubhank Sir Please check when i zoomed in this drawable xml backgroud it automatically cover behind area

Comment: ok, are you using any third party library to draw code. Please tell more how you have coded it till now

Comment: No Sir, I'm not using any third party, these images are demo from Squid App, I am trying this on this link demo: - https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ooytwg1jgjscit/ZoomSample.rar?dl=0

Comment: @Shubhank Sir can we use drawable dimentions in different size by adding pixels?